# If drilling to the mantle is too hot for drills and too hard for millimeter waves, why not use positrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, geotechnical-engineering

Would it be possible to make a millimeter sized hole which extends down to the mantle, and fill it in with a heat sink, to draw the heat upwards to a mine for steam production and then power?

Comment: how much heat do you think will travel through a 1mm whatever-it-is you're-planning-to-use?

Comment: Didn't nature give us those already? aka geysers?

Comment: the title does not match the body of the post... please correct it

Comment: Your title and question body have nothing to do with each other. Also, you do know positrons are anti-matter? Your proposed positron drill is basically an anti-matter weapon. Those are a long way from existing for that for reasons that should be obvious with any amount of research. You probably also would not want to use one for drilling because anti-matter weapons have...side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Why not?  Because the technology to do so doesn't exist yet, either for the drilling or the heat transfer.